# How Do You Translate Formatted Text in a TextBlock?

Tags: xaml, uwp, textblock

My TextBlocks contains formatting like this...

```
<TextBlock.Inlines>
    <Run x:Uid="Run1" FontWeight="Bold" FontSize="14" Text="This is UWP TextBlock Example. " />
    <Run x:Uid="Run2" FontStyle="Italic" Foreground="Red" Text="This is red text. " />
</TextBlock.Inlines>
```

I have indicated the Runs inside my Resource file as...

Run1.Text = "This is UWP TextBlock Example."

Run2.Text = "This is red text."

... but it is not getting picked up by the Multilanguage Translation tool. How can I get correct translation without the formatting getting broken?

Comment: `Run.Text` is not a dependency property, while [Run.FontSize](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.documents.run#properties) is, do an experiment, see if you can localize the `FontSize` property, if you can, then we can conclude it has to be a `DependencyProperty` in order to be localized.

Comment: You can see t both `FontSize` and `FontSizeProperty` are defined in the Run class, so you know it is a Dependency Property, many things only work on Dependency Properties, like data binding.